# В чём различия высоты дерева и количества уровней этого самого дерева

Tags: дерево

Есть построенное двоичное б-дерево, необходимо найти его высоту(которая находится как у обычного двоичного дерева) и количество уровней(которые находятся как у двоичного б-дерева). Разве эти две характеристики не одно и то же?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все зависит от того, кто задает вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy, не ясно излагаю?

Comment: Что такое `двоичное б-дерево`?

Comment: @MBo Двоичное Б-дерево состоит из вершин (страниц) с одним или двумя элементами. Следовательно, каждая страница содержит две или три ссылки на поддеревья.

Comment: [Вот это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)? Преподы тоже затейники бывают.

Comment: @Dezoway, имелось ввиду тот кто это спросил у тебя. Обычно в задачах указывают значение терминов.

Comment: @MBo именно оно

Comment: @Grundy в задании указано, думал про такие деревья многие знают, хотя практически нигде нормальной и полной информации про них нет

Comment: @MBo так вот и как количество уровней можно найти? В теор. материале ни слова. Остаётся догадываться, по логике количество уровней +-= высоте

Comment: Стандартно - высота дерева определяется количеством уровней, на которых располагаются его вершины. Почему у вас так сформулировано (какая точная формулировка?) - не знаю

Comment: @MBo  вот что указано в задании:Для построенного ДБ-дерева вычислить размер, контрольную сумму, высоту и среднюю высоту (как для двоичного дерева) и высоту ДБ-дерева как количество уровней, сравнить их с аналогичными характеристиками АВЛ-дерева.

Comment: Я думаю это кривая формулировка - если убрать первое слово "высоту и", то получается лучше